# Reddit style 'join' popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

Is reddit's join popup that appears on the page hidden on the page or is it injected via ajax?

How do they do it? (general terms if someone out there knows, I will dig into the source myself but need some guru pointers).

Answer (score 1):

For reddit, its a hidden element. You can use tools like [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) or [nyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) to achieve this kind of effect (since you can adjust the animation)

Answer (score 1):

Its not so much AJAX as it is javascript, and it is generally refered to as a [Lightbox](http://www.google.com/search?q=lightbox) or a [Dialog](http://www.google.com/search?q=dialog+jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's there but hidden with CSS, and shown with Javascript. With jquery, you could achieve the similar effect by triggering:

```
$('#join_div').show();
```

Try to view the page with CSS disabled and you'll see it's at the bottom of the page. (Optionally, you could try viewing the source.)